# regex para eliminar de un string todas las palabras de un arreglo

Tags: javascript, regex, str-replace

Como puedo hacer una regex para que elmimine de un string todas las palabras contenidas en un **arreglo** Ej: todas las palabras contenidas en mi arreglo `words=[]`.. la solucion que he encontrado hasta el momento es esta de mas abajo.. hacer varios replace con cada una de las palabras..  pero suponiendo que tengas una gran cantidad de palabras... debes hacer n replaces; imaginemos que sean 100..

```js
function clearLastPosition(str) {
    let words= ['.html', '.htm', '.php', '.asp']
 
    return str.replace(/.html/g, '').replace(/.asp/g, '').replace(/.php/g, '').replace(/[^\\d/A-Za-z]/g, " ")
}

console.log(clearLastPosition('index.php.html'));
console.log(clearLastPosition('home.html'));
console.log(clearLastPosition('home?direction.asp'));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar el operador `|` para validar diferentes patrones, por ejemplo:

```
// Generaría el string "(.html|.htm|.php|.asp)"
let reg_str = '(' + dominios.join('|') + ')'
// Sería el equivalente a /(.html|.htm|.php|.asp)/g
let regex = new RegExp(reg_str,"g")
```

Y aquí el snippet:

```js
function clearLastPosition(str) {
    let dominios= ['.html', '.htm', '.php', '.asp']
    let reg_str = '(' + dominios.join('|') + ')'
    let regex = new RegExp(reg_str,"g")
    return str.replace(regex, '').replace(/[^\\d/A-Za-z]/g, " ")
}

console.log(clearLastPosition('index.php.html'));
console.log(clearLastPosition('home.html'));
console.log(clearLastPosition('home?direction.asp'));
```

Con esto, no importa cuantos elementos tengas en el arreglo `dominios`

Comment: Muchas Gracias @gustavovelascoh me parece muy util esta forma de hacer el replace para multiples palabras.. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Lo puedes hacer directamente con una Expresión regular

```js
function clearLastPosition(str) {
    //let dominios= ['.html', '.htm', '.php', '.asp']
 
    return str.replace(/(.html|.htm|.php|.asp)+/g,"");
}

console.log(clearLastPosition('index.php.html'));
console.log(clearLastPosition('home.html'));
console.log(clearLastPosition('home?direction.asp'));
```

O en caso de que quieras que sea como tu idea de usar el array para cada expresion regular puedes hacer algo así:

```js
function clearLastPosition(str) {
    let dominios= ['.html', '.htm', '.php', '.asp'];
    
    dominios.forEach(e=>str=str.replace(new RegExp(e, "g"), ''));
    return str;
}

console.log(clearLastPosition('index.php.html'));
console.log(clearLastPosition('home.html'));
console.log(clearLastPosition('home?direction.asp'));
```

---

La [respuesta de @gustavovelascoh](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/302673/128699) fusiona ambas opciones, creo que ademas es mejor ya que te ahorras el `forEach` y múltiples `replaces`.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu respuesta me parece muy util para cualquiera que llegue aqui con la misma duda @x3k_js :)